# iPython clear cache from within function call?

Tags: python, caching, ipython

I am having memory issues with iPython, and I find that calling `%clear out` occasionally clears this out.  It seems to be caching output somewhere within some of the functions that I'm calling.

I would like to build this into my function.  `clear out` calls:

```
self.outputcache.flush()
```

How can I get a reference to the iPython shell (`self` in the above)?  In other words: how can I flush the outputcache in iPython, without using `clear`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output cache is `Out` or `_oh` in your user namespace, so you can call `Out.clear()`. **Edit**: This might be a different output cache to `self.outputcache`. I'm not so familiar with 0.10.

If you need a reference to your IPython shell, in IPython 0.10, use `__IP` or `__IPYTHON__`. In 0.11 (the development version), use `get_ipython()`.